# Increasing Letters based on a certain fields value?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a formula that uses increments of capital letters i.e. (A, B, AA, AB, etc) for every 20,000 of the field "Sum ({BATC_Batch_Tran.Total_KG}, {ORDE_Goods.Category_Code}". by using the below formula I have managed to show any value  <20,000 = 1, <40,000 = 2 etc.

int(Sum ({BATC_Batch_Tran.Total_KG}, {ORDE_Goods.Category_Code})/20000)+1

How to I convert the resultant values into capital letters? 1 = "A", 2 = "B", 27 = "AA" etc

Also, would it be possible show some sort of time stamp in the report to indicate when the Letter is increased to the next??

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Just use Chr() function. Chr(65) is 'A', Chr(66) is 'B' and so on. What do you mean with timestamp? Result of CurrentTime() function? :)

Comment: Its a bit confusing for me what do you need exactly? if the result is `1` then you want to display it as `A`?

Comment: yes Siva, if the result is 1 then the letter is shown as "A" and whenever the field value exceeds 20,000 the result will change to 2 so the letter will change to "B" etc.

@Arvo With regards to time stamping, I am wondering if it is possible for a report to sum up BATC_Batch_Tran.Total_KG and date when the value passes its 20,000 increment?

Comment: Look, you have not presented us with data definitions - how should we know, what fields you want to watch, change or summarize? Use running total formulae, these are just meant for calculating running total values :)

Comment: @craig Just to get the count up out of the way, using the answer below, is it possible after "Z" it can continue onto "AA", "AB" etc? instead of "["

Answer (score 1):

```
// define numerator and denominator
Local Numbervar n:=Sum ({BATC_Batch_Tran.Total_KG}, {ORDE_Goods.Category_Code});
Local Numbervar d:=20000;

// result of integer division added to 'A'
Chr(65+n\d);
```

Comment: After "Z" the symbol changes to "[", is there anyway for the letters to count up to "AA", "AB", "AC" etc?